# Formally deriving a vacuous truth from a definition involving conjoined implications

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation, first-order-logic

> Definition of absolute value:
>
> $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, (x \geq 0 \Longrightarrow |x| = x) \wedge (x < 0 \Longrightarrow |x| = -x)$

I want to use this definition in [one of my proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3194754/proving-an-inequality-involving-absolute-value-how-do-i-justify-using-a-conjunc). So I instantiate it below.

> Let $x  \in \mathbb{R}.$ Let us assume $x \geq 0$.
>
> Since $x \geq 0 \Longrightarrow |x| = x$, we can conclude that $|x| = x$ directly, by *modus ponendo ponens*.

I believe the above statements are correct. But is the following line also correct?

> Since $x < 0 \Longrightarrow |x| = -x$, we can also conclude that $|x| = -x$, as the implication is vacuously true.

If so, is the justification rigorous enough? Is there a logical name for this derivation (analogous to *modus ponendo ponens*)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what your question is here, but hopefully this will help:

If $x \geq 0$, then given (one part of) the definition, you can then indeed infer $|x| = x$, by Modus Ponens

And yes, given that $x \geq 0$, it is indeed (vacuously) true that $x < 0 \to |x| = -x$ ... but of course you already could have gotten that from your very definition.

What does *not* follow, however, is that $|x| = -x$.  That is, just because $x < 0 \to |x| = -x$ is true does not mean that $|x| = -x$ is true.

Comment: It seems a vacuous truth of the form $P \Rightarrow Q$ does not tell us anything about the truth value of $Q$, only about the truth value of $P$ (i.e. $P$ is false).

Comment: @Calculemus Correct ... though some would say that $P \to Q$ is also ' vacuously true' (that is, true in a non-interesting way) when $Q$ is true ...  and then from the vacuous truth of $P \to Q$ nothing can be derived regarding $P$ or $Q$ alone.